# Issue with conditionally ranking p-values

Tags: r, conditional-statements, rank

I am conducting some time series modelling and want to remove terms from my time series based on removing the lowest rank p-values. The criteria I have is to only rank p-values that exclude "ar", "ma", "intercept", "price.diff" and rank only if p>0.2.

Here is an example:

```
term         pval   rank
ar1          0.001  NA
ar2          0.292  NA   
ar3          0.000  NA
ma1          0.000  NA
intercept    0.000  NA
Price.Diff   0.859  NA
School       0.818  2
Easter       0.149  NA
Christmas    0.049  NA
High.Week    0.000  NA
Low.Week     0.000  NA
```

This is the function I have written:

```
rank_p<-function(x) {
  x["rank"]<-NA
  x$rank<-ifelse(test = substr(x$term,1,2) != "ar" & 
  substr(x$term,1,2) != "ma" & 
  substr(x$term,1,stop = nchar(x$term)) != "intercept" &
  substr(x$term,1, stop = nchar(x$term)) != "Price.Diff" & 
  x$pval > 0.2,
  yes = rank(-x$pval, na.last = NA),
  no = NA)
 return(x)
  }
```

My issue is that the rank for this example begins at 2.This would be the second highest p-value however because I am excluding price.diff, this should be ranked 1.

Is the issue in ordering of the conditions?

Comment: Your code may benefit from use of the `%in%` operator. To read about it, look at the `?match` help page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that the %in% will retur a vector of TRUE/FALSE, will i still not have the ranking issue though, unless I i base the ranking on TRUE values only?

Comment: You can use logical vectors to subset, removing the p-values that you don't want to consider in your ranking. See `?"["` if this sounds interesting.

Comment: If the 2 was instead a 1, would that be a desired output? Or would Easter and Christmas also have a ranking?

Comment: Hi Croote, correct, 2 should be a 1. Eastern and Christmas should not have a ranking as their p-value is <0.2

Comment: Great - I think I understand what it is you desire. let me know if my answer meets the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your ranking is not as desired is because your `yes` term includes the whole column. So you need to subset the column based on your condition.
What is happening in your current function is that you are ranking the column without a filter then changing to `NA` everything that doesn't fit the condition.

I have just added a slightly changed version of your code to do this.
All I changed was to define your condition then subset the data frame accordingly. EDIT: this will work on the displayed data but not if there are more than one rows which meet the condition.

```
rank_p <- function(x) {
  x["rank"] <- NA
  cond <- {substr(df$term,1,2) != "ar" & 
      substr(df$term,1,2) != "ma" & 
      substr(df$term,1,stop = nchar(df$term)) != "intercept" &
      substr(df$term,1, stop = nchar(df$term)) != "Price.Diff" & 
      df$pval > 0.2}

  x$rank <- ifelse(test = cond,
                   yes = rank(-x[cond, ]$pval, na.last = NA),
                   no = NA)
  return(x)
}
```

What this does is only rank the rows that meet your condition( `x[cond, ]` ).

This can be further simplified because you have already set them to `NA` just change the ones that meet the condition. It doesn't seem like you need an `ifelse` at all! This will also assign a vector of ranking to a subset of the same length which should work for larger sets which contain more than 1 row which meets the condition.

```
rank1_p <- function(x) {
  x["rank"] <- NA
  cond <- {substr(df$term,1,2) != "ar" & 
      substr(df$term,1,2) != "ma" & 
      substr(df$term,1,stop = nchar(df$term)) != "intercept" &
      substr(df$term,1, stop = nchar(df$term)) != "Price.Diff" & 
      df$pval > 0.2}
  x[cond, "rank"] <- rank(-x[cond,]$pval, na.last = NA)

  return(x)
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Croote. That works perfectly. I have accepted your answer. Could you just clarify that rank(-x[cond,$pval) is indexing the rows of x in column pval and that whether the meet the cond criteria. Many thanks

Comment: I see. Thinking on that question has shown me that there is another issue with the first solution and your `ifelse()` logic. It will not behave as desired because If there are multiple rows which meet the condition it will attempt to place a vector of ranks into a single row and simply take the first. 
The second solution is better and will fill the rows accordingly.

Comment: `rank` function in your case is not indexing the rows to check if they meet the condition. It is simply trying to assign the output of `rank` to the yes condition in the `ifelse`